# how spring mvc interceptor exclude some path of a special method(GET/POST/PUT)?

Tags: spring-mvc

Spring MVC Restful api

```
create Coupon POST /coupons
query Coupon GET /coupons
```

I have an interceptor, and I'd like if it is querying coupon request, it will not enter the interceptor.

```
<mvc:exclude-mapping path="/coupons" />
```

But I only want exclude `GET /coupons`, in additional `path` attribute could specify `Method` also?